# Javascript|Jquery : Script not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery

Got a weird problem that I cant fix : I've an HTML page with some javascript where I have some code that aint working, so I tried to do a simple alert but I got the same problem : the code between the tags doesnt appear when I look at the source code in the browser and I cant even see it when I look in the browser debugger...

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
     $(document).ready(function(){
        alert('hzhz') ; 
     });
 </script>
```

When I look the page source, this is what I can see :

```
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
```

If anyone has an idea or can tell me what I should look for, it will be great !

Thx !

Comment: try clear your browser cache..

Comment: did you checked entiry html, if there is some missing tag?

Comment: If it does not appear in the Source HTML it may not be the same file

Comment: did you include jquery in the `<head>`  tag?

Comment: im checking for the html if i havent forgotten any tag. @messerbill : jquery is being called in the `<head`

Comment: so please post more of your HTML code